# C++ assigning values to index 10 of an array affects index 0

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have a 2 dimensional array that is filled with info and has 10 indexes. When I run the code below :

```
for(int studentIndex = 0; studentIndex < numOfStudents; studentIndex++)
{

    if(grade[studentIndex][9] > 59){
        grade[studentIndex][10] = 1; // 1 stands for pass
    }else{
        grade[studentIndex][10] = 0; // 0 stands for fail
    }       

}
```

`grade[studentIndex][10]` changes and so does the `grade[studentIndex][0]` for the next index. the problem is somewhere there because when I `cout` index 0 before this portion, the value is fine but after this it changes to 1 or 0.

Comment: What dimensions does `grade` have?

Comment: What are the dimensions of the array? What is the value of numOfStudents?

Comment: its `int grade[numOfStudents][10]` atm

Answer (score 3):

In an array of size 10, the highest index is 9 since indexing begins at 0. I'm guessing that grade[index][10] is basically pushing the pointer forward into grade[index+1][0] and that's why you're seeing this behaviour. You'll need to either enlarge your student info array to 11 or figure out whether you're getting your indexing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

> and so does the grade[studentIndex][0] for the next index

This makes it sound like `grade` is defined as `int grade[numOfStudents][10]` (or something in that direction). The valid indices for the subarray are only `0` to `9`.